# Trying to automate a website but not getting any response after clicking button

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a website using selenium, the value is entering fine but when clicking to button without showing any response in the website the program is getting terminated what should be the reason?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("somewebsite.html");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='abc']")).sendKeys("0000");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='xyz']")).sendKeys("5020");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Click 
Me')]")).click();
//after clicking this button website is not showing any responce and 
the program terminates successfully
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//* 
[@id='pqr']")
```

Comment: Hello @Ayushi Welcome to Stack overflow , can you share more information like what have you tried and if you are getting an error then what error you are getting like this please share more information

Comment: See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on SO is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, @SAhmed I just updated the post, thanks for guiding.

Comment: @AyushiSingh You are instantiating `WebDriverWait wait` but are not using it. So the code executes succesfully. For a sensible test you should use the wait and check for some expected condition (that is: the desired response of the page).

Comment: Hi, @Würgspaß now is it right?? well I tried this too but the same problem still exist

Comment: what is the response you are expecting? Is the response visible in the page?

Comment: @SAhmed no it is not visible, I am expecting response just below the button when it gets clicked.

Comment: @AyushiSingh I cannot tell, if it is _right_ for you. That is for you determine. But it looks ok. If the element `pqr` does not appear 30 seconds after the button is clicked, you'll get an exception and the test run fails. If it does appear within 30 seconds, the test will pass. Just try it out.

Comment: @Würgspaß ok I will try.

Comment: What I meant is, after clicking the button does there anything changes visibly. like a new element appears or disappears.

Comment: @SAhmed yes after clicking button one table should appear, when I am clicking the button through automation it is not responding but when I am opening website manually in chrome and clicking the button then it is responding perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use explicit waits instead of implicit waits. Explicit waits wait for your given condition and when the condition is fulfilled it stops waiting.

Since you are waiting for something to be present after the click, wait for that element to be visible using explicit wait.

**Try this:**

```
// declare a wait first and you could reuse it
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Click Me')]"));

// instead of implicit wait this waits for the button to be clicable and doesn't wait more than necessary
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
    button.click();

    WebElement expected_element = driver.findElement(By.id("pqr"));

//this waits for your expected element to be visible after click. if the element is not visible after 30 seconds it will throw timeout exception
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(expected_element));
```

Comment: Hi @SAhmed, I've tried with "wait.untill", driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS); but still the table is not showing after the ajax call

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? If yes then post the exception stack trace.